# Putting HTML directly into the cell of a table that is populating from a json file

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

On a search results page, I have a table using the bootstrap-table plugin (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) for bootstrap that is pulling information from a json file to automatically fill out the cells.  The table looks like this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-striped="true" data-classes="table table-hover" data-url="certs2.json">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:40%" data-sortable="true" data-field="DateReturned">Date Returned</th>
          <th style="width:40%" data-sortable="true" data-field="CertNum">Certificate Number</th>
          <th style="width:20%" class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
```

In the actions column, I want to list a `<button>`, but since the cells of the bootstrap-table are automatically populating from the json file, the `<table>` won't take a `<tbody>` and I can't insert anything in the cell that isn't coming in from that json file.

What I need is a way to add a `<button>` to each cell in the Actions column, each of which will have a different link depending on the result of the Certificate Number column.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery after the table is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I studied the plugin and I think you could do what I routinely did using jQuery dataTables for angularjs. Assuming you set up a table like:

```
var plugin = $("<selector>").bootstrapTable({
    data : data,
    onPostBody : function () {
         //leverage this event to walk through the body dom and inject the fragment in appropriate cells.
    }) 
});
```

Let's say you gave your actions column like:

```
<th class="text-center" data-class="actions">Actions</th>
```

I might do something like this in the callback block:

```
  var buttonTemplate = _.template('<button class="btn btn-default action-buton" data-id="<%=id%>">Shout</button>');
 var data = plugin.getData();
 $("<table selector> tbody tr").each(function () {
     var row = $(this);
     var index = row.data("index"); //since each row element would have "data-id='...'" attribute
     row.find(".actions").html(buttonTemplate(data[index]));
  });
```

I think this should do it.